# MediaExtractor throw IOException "Failed to instantiate extractor" when extract ".m4s"

Tags: android, mp4, mediaextractor

I am trying to implement "m4s" player by mediaExtractor on Android 4.4.
However the mediaExtractor throws an IOException when set "m4s" data source.
Here is my code snippet below

```
videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
try {
    videoExtractor.setDataSource(cacheFilePath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The exception is thrown from a native method, does this mean "m4s" not supported by Android?

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
            at android.media.MediaExtractor.setDataSource(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaExtractor.setDataSource(MediaExtractor.java:159)
```

I have extracted "mp4" successfully using the same code. If Android native supports "m4s", please help to indicate which part needs to be configured.

Comment: morelikely MediaExtractor does not support mp4s